# Cannot install packages due the unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, java, dependencies, 22.04

I have dual boot boot on my laptop. I've just updated Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04. When I try to install any package with `sudo apt install` I get a message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ca-certificates-java : Depends: default-jre-headless but it is not going to be installed or
                                 java8-runtime-headless
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I try `sudo apt --fix-broken install` I get a message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  app-install-data-partner bsdmainutils chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra cpp-9 gcc-10-base:i386 gcc-9-base
  gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-cogl-1.0 gnome-getting-started-docs hwinfo libass9 libatk-wrapper-java libbdplus0
  libblas3 libboost-date-time1.71.0 libboost-filesystem1.71.0 libboost-thread1.71.0 libbrlapi0.7 libcodec2-0.9
  libcodec2-1.0 libdav1d5 libdvdnav4 libdvdread8 libffi7:i386 libfftw3-double3 libflite1 libfuse2 libfwupdplugin1
  libgdk-pixbuf-xlib-2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgfortran5 libgupnp-1.2-0 libhd21 libidn11 libigdgmm12 libllvm12:i386
  libmessaging-menu0 libmpdec2 libmpeg2-4 libntfs-3g883 libopencore-amrnb0 libopencore-amrwb0 libopenmpt0
  libpciaccess0:i386 libpgm-5.2-0 libpgm-5.3-0 libprotobuf17 libqpdf26 librubberband2 libshine3 libsidplay1v5
  libsrt1.4-gnutls libudfread0 libunoloader-java libwmf0.2-7 libx264-163 libx86emu2 libx86emu3 libxmlb1 libzimg2
  libzvbi-common libzvbi0 linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 ltrace mobile-broadband-provider-info mysql-common ncal
  popularity-contest syslinux syslinux-legacy ure-java vino
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  default-jre-headless openjdk-11-jre-headless
Suggested packages:
  default-jre fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho fonts-wqy-microhei | fonts-wqy-zenhei
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-5.13.0-39-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  default-jre-headless openjdk-11-jre-headless
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 1 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/41,5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 161 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 176890 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-5.13.0-39-generic (5.13.0-39.44~20.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-39-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-35-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-35-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-44-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-44-generic
/etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No su
ch file or directory
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.13.0-39-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.13.0-39-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.13.0-39-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I run `sudo apt update` I get:

```
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                           
Hit:3 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                                   
Hit:4 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                            
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                  
Hit:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/trebelnik-stefina/grub-customizer/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
4 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

When I try `sudo apt autoremove`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ca-certificates-java : Depends: default-jre-headless but it is not installed or
                                 java8-runtime-headless
 linux-image-5.13.0-39-generic : Depends: linux-modules-5.13.0-39-generic but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I try `sudo apt purge linux-modules-5.13.0-39-generic`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  app-install-data-partner bsdmainutils chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra cpp-9 fonts-dejavu-extra gcc-10-base:i386
  gcc-9-base gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-cogl-1.0 gnome-getting-started-docs hwinfo java-common libass9
  libatk-wrapper-java libbdplus0 libblas3 libboost-date-time1.71.0 libboost-filesystem1.71.0 libboost-thread1.71.0
  libbrlapi0.7 libcodec2-0.9 libcodec2-1.0 libdav1d5 libdvdnav4 libdvdread8 libffi7:i386 libfftw3-double3 libflite1
  libfuse2 libfwupdplugin1 libgdk-pixbuf-xlib-2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgfortran5 libgupnp-1.2-0 libhd21 libidn11
  libigdgmm12 libllvm12:i386 libmessaging-menu0 libmpdec2 libmpeg2-4 libntfs-3g883 libopencore-amrnb0
  libopencore-amrwb0 libopenmpt0 libpciaccess0:i386 libpgm-5.2-0 libpgm-5.3-0 libprotobuf17 libqpdf26 librubberband2
  libshine3 libsidplay1v5 libsrt1.4-gnutls libudfread0 libunoloader-java libwmf0.2-7 libx264-163 libx86emu2
  libx86emu3 libxmlb1 libzimg2 libzvbi-common libzvbi0 linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 ltrace
  mobile-broadband-provider-info mysql-common ncal popularity-contest syslinux syslinux-legacy ure-java vino
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-5.13.0-39-generic linux-modules-5.13.0-39-generic*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 10,2 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 176880 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-5.13.0-39-generic (5.13.0-39.44~20.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-39-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-35-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-35-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-44-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-44-generic
/etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: 
No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.13.0-39-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.13.0-39-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.13.0-39-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
W: Can not find PkgVer for 'linux-modules-5.13.0-39-generic'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include what happens when you do a simple `sudo apt update`

Comment: I did it. Check it out.

Comment: Ok I've copied my whole output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: I suggest that you remove the `xenial` source from `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Also remove any of the PPAs you added that you don't need. (See [Are PPAs safe...](https://askubuntu.com/q/35629)) Then run `sudo apt update` again followed by `sudo apt autoremove`. This will remove orphaned packages. Then you can run `sudo apt upgrade` to bring your system up-to-date. At this point, if everything was successful, you should be able to `sudo apt install packagename` for whatever package you are trying to install.

Comment: When I try to sudo apt autoremove I get a similar message with unmet dependencies. I will paste it into my question.

Comment: I want to purge linux-image-5.13.0-39-generic but I can't. Message in the post.

Comment: This answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72131976/rstudio-not-starting-on-ubuntu-22-04-error-while-loading-shared-library-libcr. Idk whether it is a valid solution but it worked.